# Update file from a .net website to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, asp.net

I need to update files from .asp web site and the files need to store in sharepoint2010 documsnt lib. i need to use sharepoint for bulk document storage.

Comment: what do you mean with, you need to update a file?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking, please provide more details about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I need to update files from .asp web site and the files need to store in sharepoint2010 documsnt lib.

Comment: i need to upload the documents from webpage to sharepoint site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sharepoint client object to update the items in sharepoint.

Check the following link to perform basic operations on Sharepoint using CSOM.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

i cant get you what you asking about updating. i think you need to see this link for reference

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19717/Uploading-files-to-the-SharePoint-Document-Library

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/update-a-file-in-a-document-library-in-sharepoint-2013-using/

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Try to include the good parts from the links in your post, and only use the links as a source to more information. If the links break your answer will be of no help to future readers